# Read data from file into different arrays in python

Tags: python, blender, readfile

I'm creating a simple script for blender and i need a little help with get some data from file i've created before via python.

That file got structure like below:

```
name first morph
values -1.0000 1.0000
data 35 0.026703 0.115768 -0.068769
data 36 -0.049349 0.015188 -0.029470
data 37 -0.042880 -0.045805 -0.039931
data 38 0.000000 0.115775 -0.068780
name second morph
values -0.6000 1.2000
data 03 0.037259 -0.046251 -0.020062
data 04 -0.010330 -0.046106 -0.019890
…
```

etc more 2k lines ;p

What i need is to create a loop that read for me those data line by line and put values into three different arrays: names[] values[] and data[] depending on first word of file line.

```
Manualy it should be like that:
names.append('first morph')
values.append( (-1.0000,1.0000))
data.append((35, 0.026703, 0.115768, -0.068769))
data.append((36, -0.049349, 0.015188, -0.029470))
data.append((37, -0.042880, -0.045805, -0.039931))
data.append((38, 0.000000, 0.115775, -0.068780))
names.append('second morph')
values.append( (-0.6000,1.2000))
…
```

I dont know why my atempts of creating that kind of 'for line in file:' loop creating more errors than complete data, i dont know why is going out of range, or not getting proper data

Please help how to automate that process instead of writing manualy each line since i already exported needed parameters into a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = []
values = []
data = []
with open('yourfile') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        first, rest = line.split(' ', 1)

        if first == 'name':
            names.append(rest)

        elif first == 'values':
            floats = map(float, rest.split())
            values.append(tuple(floats))

        elif first == 'data':
            int_str, floats_str = rest.split(' ', 1)
            floats = map(float, floats_str.split())
            data.append( (int(int_str),) + tuple(floats) )
```

Why do you need it like this? How will you know where the next name starts in your data and values lists?

Comment: I'll make a connection between name and value array index. For data array i'll add maybe one more parameter equvialent to current index in name array which will increase each time a 'name' will occur in file.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a list of morph objects (or just tuples), with name, values, and data attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple python "for line in" solution... you can just call `processed.py`...

```
fp = open("data1.txt", "r")

data = fp.readlines()
fp1 = open("processed.py", "w")

fp1.write("names = []\nvalues=[]\ndata=[]\n")

for line in data:
    s = ""
    if "name" in line:
        s = "names.append('" + line[5:].strip() + "')"
    elif "values" in line:
        s = "values.append((" + ", ".join(line[7:].strip().split(" ")) + "))"
    elif "data" in line:
        s = "data.append((" + ", ".join(line[5:].strip().split(" ")) + "))"

    fp1.write(s + "\n");

fp1.close()
fp.close()
```